# error_reporting(E_ALL) don't show any error message

Tags: php

I have a simple form that uploads a file. The file is identified by the PHP code when I `var_dump` it. But when move it using `move_uploaded_file()` functions it fails and prints `error occurred`.

I have included `error_reporting(E_ALL);` But no error is shown when above function fails.

**HTML Form:**

```
   <form method="post" action="src/blog.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="text" name="title" id="title">
      <input type="file" name="cover" id="cover">

      <textarea id="mytextarea" name="mytextarea">Hello, World!</textarea>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

**PHP Code:**

```
 <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
    require_once('Database.php');


    $content= $_POST['mytextarea'];
    $title=$_POST['title'];
    $file=$_FILES['cover']['name'];
    $target_dir="uploads/";
    $target_file=$target_dir.basename($file);
    if(move_uploaded_file($file,$target_file)){
        $db=new \src\Database();
        $db->addNewBlog($title,$target_file,$content);
    }
    else{
       echo 'error occured';
    }
```

So my question is why no error is displayed and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation:

> If filename is not a valid upload file, then no action will occur, and move_uploaded_file() will return FALSE.

So you are giving it an invalid upload file.

The reason is that move_uploaded_files is expecting the first parameter to be the temp path of the file, not the name of the file. Changing it like so may resolve your problem:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['cover']['tmp_name'], $target_file);
```